# Can anyone help me about this graph using \foreach{}

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, graphs, foreach

So I need to create thig graph using equation `y= 2ax^2±12x`

using `\foreach{}` for `a={−2.4,−2.1,...,2.4}`
Thanks in advance.

[image: This is graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=\(x\),
            ylabel=\(y\),
            xmin=-7,
            xmax=7,
            ymin=-30,
            ymax=30,
            grid=major,
            grid style={solid},
            samples=100
        ]
            \foreach \a in {-2.4, -2.1, ..., 2.4} {
                \addplot[
                    domain=-7:7, 
                    red, 
                    dashed
                ] expression{2*\a*x^2 + 12*x};
                \addplot[
                    domain=-7:7,
                    cyan
                ] 
                expression{2*\a*x^2 - 12*x};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but can you explain me how to remove some of these red and blue line so I can have lesser but same graph

Comment: Very nice and thank you to have provide to create a full mwe. +1.

Comment: Currently the `\foreach` loop is plotting for `a = -2.4, -2.1, -1.8, -1.5, ..., 2.4`, if, for example, you want to plot half as many points change `-2.1` to `-1.8` and tikz will automatically plot half as many lines. You could also just list all values of `a` that you want to plot for removing the `...` in the list of values, for example if you only want to plot for `a = -1, 0, 0.5` then change it to `\foreach \a in {-1, 0, 0.5}`. The syntax of `\foreach` is that given `\foreach \a in {x, y, ..., z}` the variable `\a` takes the values `x`, `y`,..., `z` in step sizes `y - x`.